# How to find a tree connecting all nodes in neo4j?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I want a minimum spanning tree which spans at least (but not restricted to) a set of nodes.

e.g.

Say I want a minimum spanning tree which has at least the nodes `{A,B}`. However my graph looks like this `A->C->B->D`. So the algorithm should return `A->C->B`.

I am not asking for shortest path, there can be more than two nodes I want to connect. I just want the smallest graph that is connected and includes the given set.

Comment: [This problem is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree).

Comment: Can you add what you've tried? If you haven't tried using it yet, binding a pattern variable on a pattern with variable relationships, than using comparisons with SIZE(NODES(pattern)) may help, at least in your 2-nodes case.

Comment: I am new to neo4j, I have no clue what to try. It is not supposed to be linear, I just wrote one for simplicity sake.

Comment: Does your graph have weights on the relationship edges? Usually MST assumes edges with weights. If not, we can consider all edges have the same weight as 1, and as a consequence, I think we can use the number of distinct nodes in potential trees to determine which is the MST.